# Can I acquire multiprocessing's Lock in a with statement?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, with-statement

Horrible things can happen if a process fails to unlock a `multiprocessing` lock. To minimize the chance of that happening, I want to acquire the lock in a `with` block. Is there any built in way I can do this or do I need to roll my own?

Comment: Did you try it, and what error did it raise? I would expect that to just work.

Comment: @delnan I'd expect it too. In fact instances of `Lock` do have `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods, but I couldn't find any mention of this in the documentation.

Comment: those locks are their own context managers. `with mylock:` works.

Comment: The documentation says "a clone of `threading.Lock`" in the `multiprocessing.Lock` documentation, so presumably it supports the same interface.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, you can just do:

```
mylock = multiprocessing.Lock()

with mylock:
    ...
```

as Lock is a context manager. So is RLock, and Lock and RLock from threading.

The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#synchronization-primitives) does state that it is "a clone of threading.Lock", so you can refer to ["Using locks, conditions, and semaphores in the with statement"](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#using-locks-conditions-and-semaphores-in-the-with-statement)

[edit 2020: The [documentation now mentions this explicitly](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.RLock)]

Comment: Does this code snippet make sense? I thought you had to define the lock beforehand (`lock = multiprocessing.Lock(); with lock: ...`), otherwise you just create a new lock object each time (and do effectively zero locking).

Comment: Yes you should put the object in a variable or attribute if you have something to actually protect from concurrent access. I was just demonstrating that it works with a with statement.

Answer (score 8):

Yes you can.

The documentation for [`Lock`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Lock) states:

> `class multiprocessing.Lock`
>
> ```
> A non-recursive lock object: a clone of `threading.Lock`.
> ```

Reading [`threading`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/threading.html#using-locks-conditions-and-semaphores-in-the-with-statement)'s documentation:

> All of the objects provided by this module that have `acquire()` and
>   `release()` methods can be used as context managers for a `with`
>   statement.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) now specifically states that:

> **Lock** supports the context manager protocol and thus may be used in *with* statements.